# How to show a fragment layout in landscape mode in bottom view fragments?

Tags: android, fragment, android-bottom-nav-view

I am using fragments in android bottom Navigation tabs. I want to show a layout in third navigation tab s fragment to landscape . how is it possible? . One thing I know was, we can fix the activities Rotations in Manifest file. 
Please Provide me your suggestions  and solutions

Comment: Add screenOrientationtag to Activity inside AndroidManifest.xml `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` If you wish to set orientation of an Activity to landscape.